# Matrix with all entries N

Tags: linear-algebra, matrices

Is there a specific name for a matrix where all entries are the name number? I am writing a program where I want to be able to describe a matrix like this in the same way I would the identity matrix, or a diagonal matrix.

Examples:

$$
        \begin{matrix}
        2 & 2 & 2 \\
        2 & 2 & 2 \\
        2 & 2 & 2 \\
        \end{matrix}
$$

or

$$
        \begin{matrix}
        -7.09 & -7.09 \\
        -7.09 & -7.09 \\
        -7.09 & -7.09 \\
        -7.09 & -7.09 \\
        \end{matrix}
$$

Comment: A scalar product of a [unit matrix](http://mathworld.wolfram.com/UnitMatrix.html).

Comment: I suppose you mean "scalar multiple", and not [scalar product of vectors](http://hyperphysics.phy-astr.gsu.edu/hbase/vsca.html).

Answer (score 0, accepted):

This is [a matrix of ones](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Matrix_of_ones) multiplied by a scalar.